# Call function upon list widget row change?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

In my program, I have a QListWidget, some lineEdit widgets, and a pushButton. When the user clicks on an item in the QListWidget, they can enter some information and values into the lineEdit widgets and then save that info by clicking a "Save" pushButton.

Here is an image of what my program looks like. The QListWidget in question is the one titled "Messages"

[image]

Currently, the user must click Save before selecting a different item in the Messages list.
This is my current "save" function:

```
void MainWindow::on_Mmsave_clicked()
{
    messages[ui->Mmlist->currentRow()] = ui->Mmessage->toPlainText();

    //Whatever message is currently selected, save the list of items in there

    for(int k=0; k<=ui->Milist->count()-1; k++)
        items[ui->Mmlist->currentRow()][k] = ui->Milist->item(k)->text();
}
```

This works fine, however there are many times when the user forgets to click Save before moving on to a different item in the Messages list. I want my program to "autosave" when the user switches to a different item in the Messages list.

I am aware there is a signal for the list called currentRowChanged(), but when I attempt to start the save function after currentRowChanged(), it "saves" everything into the item that was SWITCHED TO, and not the item SWITCHED FROM.

Is there any way to save all the info into the "previously selected" item in the Messages list?

EDIT: Also, I want it to save the info when the same item in the list was clicked again. Thus making the "previously selected" item the SAME item.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Keep track of the selected item in a variable. When selection changes, save changes before updating your variable with the new selection.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't just think of that before. Sorry to bother. :/